# New pdf for every different customer number

Tags: php, sql, tcpdf

I have tried to cut down the code as much as possible. The most important part of the code is the second block. There are only two scenarios where I need a different bill to address. These are hard coded in shippercarrierdata,shippercarrierdata1.These create pdfs fine. the problem is creating the default addresses for prepaid customers when there is more than one customer I need it to create a new pdf with a list of all the orders for that customer. I am using TCPDF. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    //
    include('inc/connections.php');
    $pickUpDate = $_REQUEST['pickUpDate'];

    require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    // Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
    class ManafestPrint extends TCPDF {

        //Page header
        public function Header()
        {
            global $pickUpDate;

            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
            // Title
            $titleHTML = '
                    <table width="100%" border="0" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="25%" align="left">PICK UP DATE: '.$pickUpDate.'</td>
                            <td width="50%" align="center" style="font-size: 16pt;">SHIPPING MANIFEST</td>
                            <td width="25%" align="right">Page '.$this->getPageNumGroupAlias().' of '.$this->getPageGroupAlias().'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                ';
            $this->writeHTMLCell(280, 25, 7, 5, $titleHTML);
        }


    }
    $orders = explode(',', $_REQUEST['orders']);
    $infinity = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach($orders as $order) {


        $sql = "
                SELECT
                    oeordhdr_sql.ship_via_cd AS shipper,
                    oeordlin_sql.ord_no AS ordnum,
                    oeordhdr_sql.frt_pay_cd AS thirdparty,
                    oeordhdr_sql.cus_no AS customer
                FROM oeordhdr_sql JOIN oeordlin_sql ON oeordhdr_sql.ord_no = oeordlin_sql.ord_no
                WHERE
                    oeordhdr_sql.ord_no = oeordlin_sql.ord_no
                    AND oeordlin_sql.loc IN ('PMD','OM1')
                    AND oeordhdr_sql.shipping_dt>=getdate()-21
                    AND oeordlin_sql.ord_no = ' $order'
                    ORDER BY oeordlin_sql.ord_no ASC
            ";
        $query = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($query);
    if (($row['customer']) == '0000' && ($row['thirdparty']) == 'C' && ($row['shipper']) == 'EST') {
    $tablerows= "<tr><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['ord_num'].'</td><td>'.$row['item_no'].'</td><td>'.$row['shipper'].'</td><td>'.$row['thirdpart'].'</td></tr>";
    }elseif (($row['customer']) == '0001' && ($row['thirdparty']) == 'C' && ($row['shipper']) == 'EST') {
    $tablerows1 = "<tr><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['ord_num'].'</td><td>'.$row['item_no'].'</td><td>'.$row['shipper'].'</td><td>'.$row['thirdpart'].'</td></tr>";
    }else{
    $tablerows2 = "<tr><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['ord_num'].'</td><td>'.$row['item_no'].'</td><td>'.$row['shipper'].'</td><td>'.$row['thirdpart'].'</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    $tableData = '
            <style>
                table#manifestTable tr.odd td{
                    background-color: #F0F0F0;
                }
                div.totalDIV{
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
            <table id="manifestTable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size: 8pt;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">REF#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PO#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PRO#</th>
                        <th align="left" style="width: 125px;">CONSIGNEE ADDRESS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 125px;">SPECIAL INST</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 100px;">COMMODITY</th>                 
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">NMFC#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">SUB</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">CLASS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">UNITS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">PKGS</th>
                        <th align="RIGHT" style="width: 40px;">WEIGHT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    '.$tablerows.'
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ';
    $tableData = '
            <style>
                table#manifestTable tr.odd td{
                    background-color: #F0F0F0;
                }
                div.totalDIV{
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
            <table id="manifestTable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size: 8pt;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">REF#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PO#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PRO#</th>
                        <th align="left" style="width: 125px;">CONSIGNEE ADDRESS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 125px;">SPECIAL INST</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 100px;">COMMODITY</th>                 
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">NMFC#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">SUB</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">CLASS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">UNITS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">PKGS</th>
                        <th align="RIGHT" style="width: 40px;">WEIGHT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    '.$tablerows1.'
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ';
    $tableData = '
            <style>
                table#manifestTable tr.odd td{
                    background-color: #F0F0F0;
                }
                div.totalDIV{
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
            <table id="manifestTable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size: 8pt;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">REF#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PO#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 75px;">PRO#</th>
                        <th align="left" style="width: 125px;">CONSIGNEE ADDRESS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 125px;">SPECIAL INST</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 100px;">COMMODITY</th>                 
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">NMFC#</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">SUB</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">CLASS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 40px;">UNITS</th>
                        <th align="center" style="width: 30px;">PKGS</th>
                        <th align="RIGHT" style="width: 40px;">WEIGHT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    '.$tablerows2.'
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ';

    $shipperCarierData ='
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                        <table width="250" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" width="55">Shipper:</td>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    company name<br />
                                    9000 dummy street<br />
                                    town, usa 01234<br />
                                    Jon doe (123) 456-7890
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="45"><strong>Bill To:</strong></td>
                        <td width="25%" align="left" valign="top">

                            EST<br/>
                            4444 street name<br/>
                            dummy town, 10004<br/>
                            <br/>

                    </td>               
                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="250">
                        <strong>Carrier:</strong> '.$row['shipper'].'<br />
                        <strong>Trailer#:</strong> '.$row['trailer'].'<br />
                        <strong>Service:</strong> Standard-Bill Accessorial Code WGST<br />
                        <strong>Terms:</strong> Prepaid
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
    $shipperCarierData1 ='
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                        <table width="250" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" width="55">Shipper:</td>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    company name 2<br />
                                    9000 dummy street<br />
                                    town, usa 01234<br />
                                    Jon doe (123) 456-7890
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="45"><strong>Bill To:</strong></td>
                        <td width="25%" align="left" valign="top">

                            EST<br/>
                            4444 street name<br/>
                            dummy town, 10004<br/>
                            <br/>

                    </td>               
                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="250">
                        <strong>Carrier:</strong> '.$row['shipper'].'<br />
                        <strong>Trailer#:</strong> '.$row['trailer'].'<br />
                        <strong>Service:</strong> Standard-Bill Accessorial Code WGST<br />
                        <strong>Terms:</strong> Prepaid
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
    $shipperCarierData2 ='
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 25px;">
                        <table width="250" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" width="55">Shipper:</td>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    company name<br />
                                    9000 dummy street<br />
                                    town, usa 01234<br />
                                    Jon doe (123) 456-7890
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>


                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="250">
                        <strong>Carrier:</strong> '.$row['shipper'].'<br />
                        <strong>Trailer#:</strong> '.$row['trailer'].'<br />
                        <strong>Service:</strong> Standard-Bill Accessorial Code WGST<br />
                        <strong>Terms:</strong> Prepaid
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
```

This is the pdf creation using TCPDF. I am trying to use a foreach to create a new pdf for each customer. I realize that does not work.

```
if(!empty($tablerows)) {
    $pdf->startPageGroup();
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 15, $shipperCarierData, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 3, 35, $tableData, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 160, $disclaimerHTML, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);


    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);
}
if(!empty($tablerows1)) {
    $pdf->startPageGroup();
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 15, $shipperCarierData1, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);
#WRITE TABLE ROWS
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 3, 35, $tableData1, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);




    $pdf->lastPage();
//$pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 160, $disclaimerHTML, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 160, $disclaimerHTML, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);

}
foreach($row['customer'] as $cus) {
    if (!empty($tablerows2)) {
        $pdf->startPageGroup();
        $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 15, $shipperCarierData2, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);
#WRITE TABLE ROWS
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 3, 35, $tableData2, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);




        $pdf->lastPage();

        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(280, 0, 5, 160, $disclaimerHTML, 0, 0, false, true, 'C', true);
    }
}
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('print_manifest.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1):

without seeing where you are generating this document. example have a sub Directory for each customer to store this document in. my guess would be it is because of the static naming of the actual document name.

```
$pdf->Output('print_manifest.pdf', 'I');
```

might want to dynamically name the file using the customerID or something to that effect such as

```
$filename = 'manifest' . time() . '.pdf';
$pdf->Output($filename, 'I');
```